# Can I replace a program folder with a symbolic link to another drive?

Tags: windows-10, symbolic-link

I'm using Windows 10.

I want to free up some space on my C drive, so I plan to move some programs in C:/program files(x86) to an external drive and create some symbolic links. Is this workable?

Comment: Yes, you can do this. But keep in mind, that if a program you move starts with windows, and the external drive is not connected during boot, you will get errors and incorrect behavior. Also, keep in mind that if you plug in the external drive while booting, it may want to try booting from the external drive and give you an OS not found error. If the latter happens, edit your boot settings in the bios.

Comment: Also, some programs have less problems with this than others.

Comment: Also, keep in mind, any program running cannot be moved. Close the program first, or boot into windows recovery command prompt first.

Comment: Update: I tired moving some programs in C drive to an external drive using symbolic links. They’ve been working well so far.

Comment: I've posted you an answer, so you can mark it as solved and others know you no longer need help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. But keep in mind, that if a program you move starts with windows, and the external drive is not connected during boot, you will get errors and incorrect behavior. Also, keep in mind that if you plug in the external drive while booting, it may want to try booting from the external drive and give you an OS not found error. If the latter happens, edit your boot settings in the bios.